# How do you get the color of a specific pixel on a webpage in javascript? (no canvas)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to figure out a way to find the color of a pixel on my webpage. As I have searched for an answer, all I have found is how to do this in a canvas element. Is there a way to do this for the entire page, and if so, how?

Here is an example piece of code that shows a basic part of what I am doing.

```js
//this executes whenever the mouse is moved
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {

  //this just simplifies the varables
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Position:  ( " + mouseX + " , " + mouseY + " ) | Color: " + getColor();
  //                               What command do you use to do this? Is it related to the document object? ^
});

function getColor() {
  return (" rgb ( 2, 5, 7 ) ");
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p id="info"><br></p>
  <img width="250" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/chicken/chicken_PNG2160.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought I saw a proposal for a color-picker API somewhere, but I can't find it anymore, (I may have dreamed it...). For the time being, the closest thing we can do is to ask the user the permission to record their page, paint that recording on a canvas and grab the pixels from there. Though you wouldn't have color perfection, because the video will get encoded badly. An other solution for easy cases is to use something like html2canvas which does reproduce a lot of the browser's rendering (but not all...).

Comment: Found it (by accident): https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdgeExplainers/blob/main/EyeDropper/explainer.md

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best practice, but you could set up all the elements on the page with a [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event that would tell your app what element being hovered. The app could check the element to find out what color it is.

Comment: ... and then simply calculate how the box-shadow of its neighbor influences its semit-transparent radial-gradient bakground-color and the element hidden 5 levels behind with multiple backdrop-filters in between...

Comment: Okay good points, Kaiido. What would you recommend?